# Node.js puppeteer - Downloading/Accessing a xml file and process the content

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Node.js puppeteer - How do I download, access and process a xml file and the content in puppeteer?

When clicking on a link like:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('#datagrid > div > a:nth-child(2)').click();
});
```

... I can download a xml file looking like this:

XML file:

```
<table>
    <row>
        <column>Titel01</column>
        <column>Titel02</column>
        <column>Titel03</column>
        <column>Titel04</column>
        <column>Titel05</column>
        <column>Titel06</column>
        <column>Titel07</column>
        <column>Titel08</column>
        <column>Titel09</column>
        <column>Titel10</column>
        <column>Titel11</column>
        <column>Titel12</column>
        <column>Titel13</column>
        <column>Titel14</column>
        <column>Titel15</column>
        <column>Titel16</column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column>Value01</column>
        <column/>
        <column>Value03</column>
        <column>Value04</column>
        <column>Value05</column>
        <column>Value06</column>
        <column>Value07</column>
        <column>Value08</column>
        <column>Value09</column>
        <column>Value10</column>
        <column>Value11</column>
        <column>Value12</column>
        <column>Value13</column>
        <column>Value14</column>
        <column>Value15</column>
        <column>Value16</column>
    </row>
    ... // starting possible more rows
    <row>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column/>
        <column>Value15B</column>
        <column>Value16B</column>
    </row>
    ... // possible 
</table>
```

How can I access the values and store it in variables to further process it in puppeteer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best solution but works. I would return, instead of `.click()` the href value with `document.querySelector('#datagrid > div > a:nth-child(2)').href;` and do another `.goto` once you open the new page, you could parse it. Here a full example:

```
const newPage = await page.evaluate(() => {

       return document.querySelector('#datagrid > div > a:nth-child(2)').href;

        });

    await page.goto(newPage, {waitUntil: 'load'});   

    const newPage2 = await page.evaluate(() => {//<-- open the new page

        var columns = document.getElementsByTagName("column");      

        var values = {"values":[]};

        for(let f in columns){
            values.values.push(columns[f].innerText);
        }

        return JSON.stringify(values);//<-- return the values of columns

         });

    console.log(JSON.parse(newPage2))//<-- we have all values
```

Comment: I'm getting { values: [ null, null, null ] } when running it. What might cause this?

Comment: @PhilippM  l guess that is because colums have null values

Comment: ... no ... the the columns are filled with values

Comment: Can I send you a link in the chat?

Comment: @PhilippM Yes, but I'm not in a computer now.

Comment: I'm sorry ... it's actually working just fine, thanks! ... yet it's not working when trying to access a txt file ... see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036054/node-js-puppeteer-fetching-content-from-a-complex-txt-file Would you happen to know how to do so?