# Node.js puppeteer - Fetching content from a complex txt file

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

How can I download, access and process a complex txt file in puppeteer?

I can access a xml file ([Node.js puppeteer - Downloading/Accessing a xml file and process the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51875386/node-js-puppeteer-downloading-accessing-a-xml-file-and-process-the-content)) like this:

```
await page.goto(myPage, {waitUntil: 'load'});   

const newPage = await page.evaluate(() => {

    var columns = document.getElementsByTagName("VALUEA");      

    var values = {"values":[]};

    for(let f in columns){
        values.values.push(columns[f].innerText);
    }

    return JSON.stringify(values);

});

console.log(JSON.parse(newPage))
```

Which returns me the desired values. But if I want to access a txt file looking like this ... and for testing want to fetch all 'VALUEA' I get:

```
{"values":[null,null,null]}
```

That's the TXT file I'm looking at:

```
<XYZ-DOCUMENT>117.txt : 20180824
<XYZ-HEADER>117.hdr.sgml : 20180824
<VALUE00>20180824153107
VALUE01:        117
VALUE02:    ABC

COMPANY:

    COMPANY DATA:   
        VALUE03:            Some Company
        VALUE04:            777

    BUSINESS ADDRESS:   
        VALUE05:        Some street
        VALUE06:            Some city

</XYZ-HEADER>
<DOCUMENT>
<VALUE07>ABC
<SEQUENCE>1
<FILENAME>primary_doc.xml
<TEXT>
<XML>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Submission xmlns="http://www.xyz.it/abc/" xmlns:com="http://www.xyz.it/abc/common">
  <headerData>
    <VALUE08>ABC</VALUE08>
    <xxxInfo>
      <xxx>
        <credentials>
          <VALUE09>777</VALUE09>
          <VALUE10>XXXXXXXX</VALUE10>
        </credentials>
      </xxx>
      <VALUE11>06-30-2018</VALUE11>
    </xxxInfo>
  </headerData>
  <bodyData>
    <coverPage>
      <VALUE12>06-30-2018</VALUE12>
      <VALUE13>1</VALUE13>
      <amendmentInfo>
        <VALUE14>STRAWBERRIES</VALUE14>
      </amendmentInfo>
      <xxxManager>
        <VALUE15>Corp</VALUE15>
        <address>
          <VALUE16:street1>MOUNTAIN STREET</VALUE16:street1>
          <VALUE17:city>NEW YORK</VALUE17:city>
        </address>
      </xxxManager>
      <provideInfoForInstruction5>N</provideInfoForInstruction5>
    </coverPage>
  </bodyData>
</Submission>
</XML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>INFORMATION TABLE
<SEQUENCE>2
<FILENAME>xml_xyz.xml
<TEXT>
<XML>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<informationTable xmlns="http://www.xyz.it/abc/informationtable" xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<infoTable>
<VALUEA>Company A</VALUEA>
<VALUEB>INC</VALUEB>
<shParent>
<VALUEC>123</VALUEC>
<VALUED>AB</VALUED>
</shParent>
</infoTable>
<infoTable>
<VALUEA>Company B</VALUEA>
<VALUEB>LTD</VALUEB>
<shParent>
<VALUEC>567</VALUEC>
<VALUED>ST</VALUED>
</shParent>
</infoTable>

...

</informationTable>
</XML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
</XYZ-DOCUMENT>
```

At the end I want to get all VALUE (primarly the VALUEA, VALUEB, VALUEC, VALUEC)! How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution to get the text content from `VALUEA`, `VALUEB`, `VALUEC`, and `VALUED`:

```
const example = await page.evaluate( () =>
{
    const page = document.createElement( 'html' );
    const page_content = document.body.textContent;

    page.innerHTML = page_content;

    return {
        'VALUEA' : Array.from( page.getElementsByTagName( 'VALUEA' ), e => e.textContent ),
        'VALUEB' : Array.from( page.getElementsByTagName( 'VALUEB' ), e => e.textContent ),
        'VALUEC' : Array.from( page.getElementsByTagName( 'VALUEC' ), e => e.textContent ),
        'VALUED' : Array.from( page.getElementsByTagName( 'VALUED' ), e => e.textContent )
    };
});

console.log( example.VALUEA[0] ); // Company A
console.log( example.VALUEA[1] ); // Company B

console.log( example.VALUEB[0] ); // INC
console.log( example.VALUEB[1] ); // LTD

console.log( example.VALUEC[0] ); // 123
console.log( example.VALUEC[1] ); // 567

console.log( example.VALUED[0] ); // AB
console.log( example.VALUED[1] ); // ST
```

Answer (score 2):

To read as dom elements html/xml inside txt one possible solution is creating a dummy dom node, like this:

```
var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
 el.innerHTML = "<tagelement>content</tagelement>";  

var columns = el.getElementsByTagName("tagelement");
```

So in your example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
```

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
      });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://example.com/file.txt', {waitUntil: 'load'});

```
const newPage = await page.evaluate(() => {

    var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
    el.innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].innerText;

    var allValues = el.querySelectorAll("VALUEA, VALUEB, VALUEC, VALUED");  

    var values = {};

    for(let i = 0; i<allValues.length; i++){
        if(!(allValues[i].nodeName in values)){
            values[allValues[i].nodeName] = [];
        }
        values[allValues[i].nodeName].push(allValues[i].innerText);

         }

        values =  JSON.stringify(values);

        return values;
    });

 console.log(JSON.parse(newPage))
```

})();

Comment: I'm still getting {} or undefined if I 'return columns' and 'console.log(newPage)'. And the fiddle shows the structure in a html format ...

Comment: @PhilippM Then maybe you are pointing to the wrong file. What happens if you open the xml url using the regular browser? The way document.getElementsByTagName works is the same as html

Comment: It's not a .xml file in this case ... it's a .txt file now. I was converted from an xml to a txt file ...

Comment: @PhilippM good point, I found a solution. I've updated the answer. That works reading a txt file with your xml.

Comment: Now it works great! By any chance, could you extend your example by adding the values VALUEB, VALUEC and VALUED?

Comment: @PhilippM I've updated the answer, that should work.