# Node.js puppeteer - Fetching data from txt files with different ElementTags

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to loop over a bunch of txt files to get some values:

txt file (being fetched)

```
<ABC-DOCUMENT>520.txt
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>INFORMATION TABLE
<SEQUENCE>2
<FILENAME>infotable.xml
<TEXT>
<XML>
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<informationTable xsi:schemaLocation="/document/thirteenf/informationtable" xmlns="/document/thirteenf/informationtable" xmlns:n1="/document/thirteenf/informationtable" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <infoTable>
    <valueA>Company A</valueA>
    <valueB>INC</valueB>
    <shParent>
        <valueC>123</valueC>
        <valueD>AB</valueD>
    </shParent>
    </infoTable>
    <infoTable>
    <valueA>Company B</valueA>
    <valueB>LTD</valueB>
    <shParent>
        <valueC>567</valueC>
        <valueD>ST</valueD>
    </shParent>
  </infoTable>
</informationTable>
</XML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
</ABC-DOCUMENT>
```

I use the below query (Post: [Node.js puppeteer - Fetching content from a complex txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036054/node-js-puppeteer-fetching-content-from-a-complex-txt-file)) to loop over the files:

my script:

```
const example = await page.evaluate( () =>
{
    const page = document.createElement( 'html' );
    const page_content = document.body.textContent;

    page.innerHTML = page_content;

    return {
        'valueA' : Array.from( page.getElementsByTagName( 'valueA' ), e => e.textContent ),
        'valueB' : Array.from( page.getElementsByTagName( 'valueB' ), e => e.textContent ),
        'valueC' : Array.from( page.getElementsByTagName( 'valueC' ), e => e.textContent ),
        'valueD' : Array.from( page.getElementsByTagName( 'valueD' ), e => e.textContent )
    };
});

console.log( example.valueA[0] ); // Company A
console.log( example.valueA[1] ); // Company B

console.log( example.valueB[0] ); // INC
console.log( example.valueB[1] ); // LTD

console.log( example.valueC[0] ); // 123
console.log( example.valueC[1] ); // 567

console.log( example.valueD[0] ); // AB
console.log( example.valueD[1] ); // ST
```

Some of the files have ns1: at the beginning though:

txt file (being skipped at the moment):

```
<ABC-DOCUMENT>006.txt
<DOCUMENT>
<TEXT>
<XML>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:informationTable xmlns:ns1="/document/thirteenf/informationtable">
  <ns1:infoTable>
    <ns1:valueA>Company D</ns1:valueA>
    <ns1:valueB>INC</ns1:valueB>
    <ns1:shParent>
        <ns1:valueC>567</ns1:valueC>
        <ns1:valueD>AB</ns1:valueD>
    </ns1:shParent>
  </ns1:infoTable>
  <ns1:infoTable>
    <ns1:valueA>Company F</ns1:valueA>
    <ns1:valueB>Corp</ns1:valueB>
    <ns1:shParent>
        <ns1:valueC>692</ns1:valueC>
        <ns1:valueD>Ave</ns1:valueD>
    </ns1:shParent> 
  </ns1:infoTable>    
</ns1:informationTable>
</XML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
</ABC-DOCUMENT>
```

So all those files are being skipped at the moment. How can I also read those files and get the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to help select the appropriate elements, and then you can use the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to extract the `textContent` back to your original array:

```
const example = await page.evaluate( () =>
{
    const page = document.createElement( 'html' );
    const page_content = document.body.textContent;

    page.innerHTML = page_content;

    const all_elements = Array.from( page.querySelectorAll( '*' ) );

    return {
        'valueA' : all_elements.filter( e => e.tagName.endsWith( 'VALUEA' ) ).map( e => e.textContent ),
        'valueB' : all_elements.filter( e => e.tagName.endsWith( 'VALUEB' ) ).map( e => e.textContent ),
        'valueC' : all_elements.filter( e => e.tagName.endsWith( 'VALUEC' ) ).map( e => e.textContent ),
        'valueD' : all_elements.filter( e => e.tagName.endsWith( 'VALUED' ) ).map( e => e.textContent )
    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get nothing returned ... console.log( records.valueA.length ); gives me 0 in both cases

Comment: ... it seems like the .filter( e => e.tagName.endsWith( 'valueA' ) ) part is not working ...

Comment: It should be working. I tested it on my side. Try checking for the `length` of `example`, rather than `records`: `console.log( example.valueA.length );`

Comment: mmh ... if I do a console.log(example.length) ... I get 'undefined'. And when I do a console.log(example) ... I get { valueA: [ ], valueB: [ ], valueC: [ ], valueD: [ ] }

Comment: Try running these full examples: [Example #1](https://puppeteersandbox.com/bpInfpZc) and [Example #2](https://puppeteersandbox.com/3ABESnpe).

Comment: Now it works thanks. And I found my mistake ... I need to use just uppercase letters. So altough in the files the tag names are <valueA>Company A</valueA> ... I need to use .endsWith( 'VALUEA' ) ... why might that be?