# Node.js puppeteer - Fetching data from txt files with no tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm using node.js and puppeteer to get some data from an txt file. The body of the file has tags and I can fetch the data ... but in the HEADER I have sth like this:

```
<ABC-HEADER>0123
<DATETIME>201811
NUMBER:     0123
TYPE:   ABC
DATE:   20181114

SENDER:

    COMPANY DATA:   
        NAME:           Company
        STATE:          WI

    BUSINESS ADDRESS:   
        STREET 1:       PO BOX 123
        STREET 2:       V123
        CITY:           VALLEY 123
        STATE:          WI
        ZIP:            123
        BUSINESS PHONE:     123

    OTHER VALUES:
        OTHER NUMBER:   068-16975
        FILM NUMBER:    13362274

    MAIL ADDRESS:   
        STREET 1:       PO BOX 456
        STREET 2:       V456
        CITY:           VALLEY 456
        STATE:          WI
        ZIP:            456
</ABC-HEADER>
```

How can I fetch those values ?!

```
const records = await page.evaluate( () =>
  {
      const page = document.createElement( 'html' );
      const page_content = document.body.textContent;

      page.innerHTML = page_content;

      ...

  });
```

Comment: Is it a text file or a HTML file? Because if it's just a text while why do you want to use puppeteer? You could just download it and use a regex to extract the data.

Comment: There are multiple a text files located on a server. ... and I use puppeteer to go through the body and extract some data similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52036054/node-js-puppeteer-fetching-content-from-a-complex-txt-file. But now I also want some data of this Header part.

Comment: Looks like you are using DOM elements as XML parser.. I would recommend you use a regex for this instead. Which string do you want to extract exactly? `0123`? Or the text after `<datetime>`?

Comment: Can you provide an example for one value? The two most important would be OTHER NUMBER and FILM NUMBER. If I have the structure I can try the others by myself.

Comment: Added an answer with an example for both values :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have that data in a string, I would recommend to *not* use puppeteer to parse the data as the data is not valid HTML (not even valid XML). You should use a regular expression instead (maybe in addition to some string splitting).

**Example**

```js
const data = '<ABC-HEADER>...'; //

const otherNumber = data.match(/OTHER NUMBER: +(\S.*)/);
console.log(otherNumber[1]); // 068-16975

const filmNumber = data.match(/FILM NUMBER: +(\S.*)/);
console.log(filmNumber[1]); // 13362274
```

This uses the [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function to match a part of a string to a given regular expression. The expressions match any the particular string (e.g. `OTHER NUMBER` followed by at least one space (`+`), followed by a single character other than white space (`\S`) followed by any data.